# FastExport script for loading data into Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, teradata

I am new to the FastExport script.

Can anyone give me an example FastExport script for loading data from Teradata into Hadoop.

I need the entire script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you can't FastExport directly from Teradata to Hadoop.
But there's a new Teradata Conector for Hadoop which supports both import and export.

http://developer.teradata.com/connectivity/articles/teradata-connector-for-hadoop-now-available

The tutorial shows sample scripts to export to Hadoop:

https://developer.teradata.com/sites/all/files/Teradata%20Connector%20for%20Hadoop%20Tutorial%20v1%200%20final.pdf

Comment: O.K. So what is FastExport used for?

Comment: Is the connector the only option to load data into Hadoop from Teradata?

Comment: I'm sure there are other options. FastExport will produce a flat file from Teradata which you would then have to write the corresponding load process into Hadoop based on the tools available within your organization and the skill set at your organization.

Comment: So, Just for my understanding, We use FastExport script to export data from Teradata into a flat file into my system. Please correct me if I am wrong. And from my system i can load this flat file into hadoop or any other databases. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, you're right :-) But why creating an intermediate file when there's a one-step process using the Connector?

Comment: Yes. I know about the connector. I happen to come across the FastExport concept so was curious. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I have one more question. After we use FastExport to get the data from Teradata into my system. What can i use to put it into Hadoop?

Comment: Oops, i'm not a Hadoop guy, but you can import using pig or hive or other load tools. You just need to export in the correct format (probably tab-delimited) and that's not easy using FastExport